# typed arrays vs arrays use cases webgl

Tags: javascript, arrays, typed-arrays

I am a newbie with typed arrays. I looked at few docs online. But, confused - can someone explain in lamen terms?

When is typed array more useful than Arrays? 
It seems typed arrays are useful when you want to build visualizations using WebGL. What about in a typical JavaScript web development?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typed arrays are more efficient, because they are limited to contain numbers (in contrast to normal arrays, which can contain elements of any type, even of different types in the same array). Typed arrays are useful when dealing with binary data (including images for visualisation), but are not commonly used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - can you explain or point me to good references for basic image visualization - typed array vs array

Comment: Sorry, I don't have good references at hand. But basically every (modern, canvas-based) image visualisation/manipulation library does use typed arrays of pixels or other bytes.

Comment: Other Experts / Bergi: I would like to see how they are being used, so I can understand how experts are using it and will help me understand better.

Comment: Then just dive into some example code. Start with the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays, then go read the source of your favourite canvas/image/WebGL library.